# Javascript d3 bar chart not working

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, elasticsearch

I am following Mike Bostock's tutorial on Bar Chart with d3 framework. I want to make bar chart from elasticsearch response.
I am facing problem when one line from his code not working for me for no reason. My code:

HTML: index.html

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ping();
        query1();
        query2();
        query3();
    </script>
    <div id="bar-chart"></div>
    <div id="pie-chart"></div>
    <div id="bar-chart2"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:
    main.js

```
function query3() {
    client.search({
      index: 'twitter',
      body: {
          size: 0,
          query: {
            query_string: {
              query: "*"
            }
          },
          aggs: {
            touchdowns: {
              terms: {
                field: "user.screen_name",
                size: 10,
                order: {
                  _count: "desc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        var data = resp.aggregations.touchdowns.buckets;
        console.log(data);

        // d3 donut chart
        var canvas2 = d3.select("#bar-chart2").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 960)
            .attr("height", 500)

        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!!!!!!
        console.log("test")
        var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
            y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
        console.log("test1")
        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.doc_count; })]);

          g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

          g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"))
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", 6)
              .attr("dy", "0.71em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Frequency");

          g.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("class", "bar")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key); })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.doc_count); })
              .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
              .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.doc_count); });
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    }); 
}
```

output: [image: safari screenshot]
console:

```
test
```

data object:

```
[{key: "carfindlychevy", doc_count: 12243}, {key: "carfindlyjeep", doc_count: 9876}, {key: "carfindlycali", doc_count: 7879}, {key: "carfindlyny", doc_count: 7737}, {key: "carfindly", doc_count: 7287}, {key: "carstexas", doc_count: 6663}, {key: "carfindlyfl", doc_count: 6617}, {key: "carfindlyaudi", doc_count: 6061}, {key: "carfindlymer", doc_count: 5604}, {key: "carfindlybmw", doc_count: 5480}]
```

I am working on macOSx + Safari. I hope I provided all needed information, thanks for your advice.

Comment: perhaps sharing how your data looks like could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your JavaScript code at the end of all HTML elements, your code is correct, however it executes before HTML elements are initialized and because of that it cannot find bar-chart2 and/or svg.

Edit:

From your screenshot I see that you use V2. There has been some changes between D3 versions and the functions such as scaleBand do not exist before V4. Therefore, use V4 when importing:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: I edited code like this: http://imgur.com/a/Z4W0Y but nothing new happens. Weird thing is that previous charts are working fine. First chart is from query1, second from query2 and so on..

Comment: I made another edit based on your screenshot, it looks like a version issue this time @bzadm

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. Now my other charts not working because they used old version of d3.js, but at least I know where is the problem so I'll try to fix them. @Vacece